# Stream commands to WSL

Tags: c#, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .net-6.0

I'm trying to write a console application that starts `wsl` in a background process and streams different commands to it for some automation stuff.

**Important:** I cannot just do `wsl -- mycommand` and then exit as I need `wsl` to stay running in the background thus I chose to keep the process alive as long as my application runs.

To start the process I'm using `Process.Start`

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName               = "wsl",
    CreateNoWindow         = true,
    RedirectStandardInput  = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError  = true,
    UseShellExecute        = false
};

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

To execute commands I just feed them into `process.StandardInput` followed by `\n`

```
process.StandardInput.Write("uname -a\n");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
```

After that I'm able to read the commands output using e.g. `process.StandardOutput.ReadLine`.

The problem with the code is that I'm not able to detect when the command finished i.e. there will be no more output to capture.
`uname -a` outputs a single line so that case is easy to handle but what if the command writes multiple lines to stdout?

Is there a way to solve this or is my approach to do this already wrong to start with?
(I need a synchronous way to get the output after executing the command as I need to evaluate it after execution)

Comment: The easiest way to detect whether command has finished would be to create a new WSL process for each command. It will incurr a longer startup time but at least you would know when the process has ended.

Comment: Can I ask why you need WSL to stay running? Just realised my first comment is probably not what you're asking for, but it may be the only/best/most reliable way.

Comment: To shorten the longer start up you could create a dummy process using something like: `wsl read a`, which you can keep doing nothing, but keeping wsl alive, as long as you need it.

Comment: To be fair, having run a simple `wsl ls` from Powershell the result was almost instantaneous. It's unlikely that the startup time of WSL is going to be an issue compared with the run time of the command.

Comment: @phuzi Well ok I'm a bit confused now. I tried something yesterday on another machine and whenever I closed the last instance of wsl all of its services were shut down too, that's why I wanted to keep the wsl process alive. On my machine this doesn't happen e.g. when I start an nginx process it keeps running when I close wsl. Maybe I have to look into that again